# How should I document a higher-order Python function?

Tags: design, python, documentation, higher-order-functions

I'm interested in designing a high level function in Python, (I.E. a function that takes other functions as arguments) but I don't know of any good conventions for documenting such a function. For example let's say I have a function "low_level" that takes an int and returns an int.

```
def low_level(x):
    """
    x: int
    """
    return x + 5
```

And suppose I want to write a function "high_level" that takes a function like low_level as its input.

```
def high_level(f):
    return f(5)
```

How should I document high_level to make it clear what the arguements and output of the function "f" are? I had this idea of defining a "class" of functions that high_level can accept as arguments, but I've heard that function typing isn't possible in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good first step would be to use type hints:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from typing import Callable, TypeVar


def low_level(x: int) -> int:
    return x + 5


T = TypeVar("T")


def high_level(f: Callable[[int], T]) -> T:
    return f(5)
```

This already tells you everything you need to know: `high_level` takes a `Callable` object as its argument, which in turn gets passed an `int` and returns "something", and that "something" is also the return type of `high_level`.

As for documentation, I would follow the style of the Python standard library, which contains many higher-order functions such as [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate).

I am not very familiar with Python documentation generators, but I would assume that the documentation for `high_level` would be rendered something like this:

> ## `high_level<T>(f: int → T) → T`